# PHP Paypal DoDirectPayment Method

Tags: php, paypal

Im getting this response from paypal and don't know how to work with it:

"The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts".

These are the values Im passing, though just examples:

- `$_POST["AMT"] = 41.95`
- `$_POST["SHIPPINGAMT"] = 19.95`
- `$_POST["NETAMT"] = 22`

Not sure if the values have something to do with the problem. I supplied all of the required fields according to the API and Im using the DoDirectPayment method.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could fix your problem.
I believe paypal requires you to have two digits after the decimal point so your netamt should be 22.00